# Strange readings from external ADC

Tags: arduino, adc

I am using external ADC MCP33121-10 via SPI interface. I need to isolate this ADC from main procesor (Arduino Mega), so I used optocouplers.

The ADC worked fine without optocouplers but when I connected them, I can't get any readings. Then I found that the error was in speed (optocouplers couldn't transmit data this fast.)

I tried slower transmission speed in traditional Arduino SPI library, but it didn't work, so I had to write my own library.

Here is sample code:

```
unsigned int data=0;

  for (int i=0;i<14;i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(CLC, HIGH);
    delay(1);
    data=data | (digitalRead(MISO)<<(14-1-i));
    digitalWrite(CLC, LOW);
    delay(2);
  }

  Serial.println(data);
```

This code works fine without optocouplers too, but when I tried it with them, I get the error (described below).

(ADC input is connected to potentiometer and I am slowly increase and then decrease voltage with potentiometer.)

The output looks like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea what can cause this problem (those little spikes at bottom and in the middle?)

Edit:

Here is same code, same hardware, just without optocouplers:

[image]

(It's not linear, because I controlled potentiometer by hand, but it shows that those "magical spikes" dissepeared.)

Edit2:

The ADC is conected this way (the ic at the bottom is 1.8V generator, jumpers SJ7 and SJ4 are shorted and SJ6 is connected to VREF):

[image]

The optocouplers are connected this way:

[image]

(MOSI is used for other purpose)

UPDATE:

I found out when I touch the MISO pin (on ADC side) with my finger it just mysteriously started working. So I added on that pin small capacitor and I am finally geting correct readings.

Does anybody knows what my finger or capacitor did with that pin?? Why it started working?

Here is placement of that cap (left side): 
[image]

Comment: A schematic would be helpful. Have you grounded the input circuit (eg. the potentiometer shell or isolated ground) to avoid noise pickup from your hands?

Comment: A Cap. can smooth out stiction on pot    Crosstalk of digital SAR noise to Analog Ground will create noise near major transitions of xxx0111... to xxxx1000xx like mid scale

Comment: You don't have a scope do you?

Comment: Yes, I have a scope. I tried to measue some noise, but I found just some small ripples in mV. I do not think that its a nose because signal is very stable. Just in some positions it creates a large jump (like in the picture).
Is possible that the chip is damaged? (I dont have another, so I cant try).

Comment: Are the opto-couplers on the data lines? Are you using a single bi-directional optocoupler, or multiple? How are you running the clock? What speed? Does it go through the opto coupler too? A schematic would be a lot of help here in helping figure this out.

Comment: Yes, opto-couplers are on data lines. Clock has 1kHz and i tried slower, but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: _"I do not think that its a nose because signal is very stable."_ Set the pot to produce one of the anomalous readings (eg. reading 0 when it should be 5000). Scope the ADC power supply, reference, and input voltages. Then scope the SPI signals on each side of the opto-couplers. Is the incorrect code being sent, or it is being distorted by the optos?

Comment: Hint, use a large capacitor discharging into a resistor as your test analogue voltage for your ADC, produces very low noise, runs itself, can be isolated, and goes through all voltage values so can test for missing codes. Put clock through optos too, to get common clock/data skew.